# Incomplete output result (dictionary in dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary

```
users = {
    'aeinstein' : {
        'first': 'albert',
        'last': 'einstein',
        'location': 'princeton',
    },

    'mcurie': {
        'first': 'marie',
        'last': 'curie',
        'location': 'paris', 
    },
    }

for username, user_info in users.items():
    print(f"\nUsername: {username}")
    full_name = f"{user_info['first']} {user_info['last']}"
    location = user_info['location']

print(f"\tFull name: {full_name.title()}")
print(f"\tLocation: {location.title()}")
```

'Username: aeinstein

Username: mcurie
Full name: Marie Curie
Location: Paris'
'I can not see full result in output'

Answer (score 2):

Your final two `print()` statements are outside of your `for` loop, hence they're not getting read. Try indenting them to the same level as your loop:

```py
...

for username, user_info in users.items():
    print(f"\nUsername: {username}")
    full_name = f"{user_info['first']} {user_info['last']}"
    location = user_info['location']

    print(f"\tFull name: {full_name.title()}")
    print(f"\tLocation: {location.title()}")
```

Which prints:

```py
Username: aeinstein
    Full name: Albert Einstein
    Location: Princeton

Username: mcurie
    Full name: Marie Curie
    Location: Paris
```